# Why is classififying space of $Z$ isomorphic to $S^1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory

I have problems understanding the classifying space of a discrete group $G$ in terms of the standard simplicial model $BG=EG/G$, where $EG$ is defined as follows:
$$
EG=\left( \coprod_{n \geq 0} \, \Delta^n \times \mathcal{E}G(n) \right) / \sim.
$$
Here, $\mathcal{E}G$ is the standard simplicial set with $\mathcal{E}G(\underline{n})=G^{n+1}$ and so on. The space $EG$ carries a diagonal $G$-action which is modded out in order to get $BG$.

It is well-known that the classifiying space of the infinite cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}=\langle g \rangle$ is isomorphic to $S^1$. However, I don't even understand this easy example:

For example, I read that $E\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{R}$. Why is that? We have for example a 2-cell $[e,g,g^2] \in E\mathbb{Z}$, which has faces $[e,g], [e,g^2]$ and $[g,g^2]$. I don't really see how this collapses by using the identifications with respect to faces and degeneracies..

Comment: By "isomorphic" do you mean "homotopy equivalent"?  Probably the easiest way to see that for $\mathbb{Z}$ and $S^1$ is to use the property that the identity homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ induces a map $S^1\to E\mathbb{Z}$ that's an isomorphism on $\pi_1$, and then since $S^1$ has trivial higher homotopy groups this is a weak homotopy equivalence, so by Whitehead's theorem it's a homotopy equivalence. Also $\mathbb{R}$ is a contractible covering space of $S^1$.

Comment: @Kyle Miller Thx! I agree, but I actually wanted to see it directly using the above construction. So, you're implying that $BG$ as I defined it is only homotopy equivalent to $S^1$, but not isomorphic as a CW-complex?

Comment: It's definitely not isomorphic as a CW complex. Inside $E\mathbb{Z}$ is a copy of $\mathbb{R}$ that you can deformation retract onto, with cell $[g^n,g^{n+1}]$ being identified with the interval $[n,n+1]$.  For example, $[g^n,g^{n+2}]$ (which is outside this subcomplex) would homotope through the cell $[g^n,g^{n+1},g^{n+2}]$ to the composite of $[g^{n},g^{n+1}]$ and $[g^{n+1},g^{n+2}]$.

Comment: I see, thank you! so appearently the above construction has much more redundancies than i thought..